# Simple rails search to check if email exist, if found, trigger email to be sent to the email that was entered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I have a page where users can enter email if they can't remember their login page to their subdomain url, but I am not able to set it up correctly.

I have an Account table in the public tenant with email table. And I receive this error: undefined local variable or method `account' for #

Here's what I have on the search page

find_login.html.erb:

```rb
    <div class="form-inputs">
     <%= form_tag(find_login_path, :method => "get") do %>
       <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Email Address", class: "form-control" %>
       <%= submit_tag "Continue", :name => nil, class: "btn btn-default" %>
     <% end %>   
    </div>
```

accounts_controller.rb:

```
def find_login
    @accounts  = Account.find_by_email(params[:search].to_s.downcase)

    unless @accounts.nil?
        flash[:success] = "Email found! An email has been sent."
        UserMailer.login_recovery(account).deliver
      else
        flash[:error] = "Email NOT found!"  if params[:search] && !params[:search].empty?
    end
end
```

user_mailer.rb:

```
def login_recovery(account)
  @account = account
  mail  to: @account.email, subject: 'Your login recocery'
end
```

Comment: Not for nothing, but just standard rails set up - you should use `@account` as you are only finding one account by the email address.

Answer (score 2):

You store the found Account in the instance variable `@accounts`, but you pass a local variable `account` to the Mailer.

Just change

```
UserMailer.login_recovery(account).deliver
```

to

```
UserMailer.login_recovery(@accounts).deliver
```

---

Or as a rewrite of the method:

```
def find_login
  query = params[:search].presence

  if query
    account = Account.find_by_email(query.downcase)

    if account
      UserMailer.login_recovery(account).deliver
      flash[:success] = "Email found! An email has been sent."
    else
      flash[:error] = "Email NOT found!"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it should be `@accounts` with an s, since he use `@accounts  = Account.find_by_email(`.

Comment: Great, thanks! 
I updated it like you suggested (@account), and the next issue is now in the user_mailer.rb, with error msg "undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass"

`mail  to: @account.email, subject: 'Login recovery'`

Comment: @lilcoder You should use `@accounts` with an s. `@account` is not defined in `find_login`. That's why it's `nil`.

Comment: Yes, that worked! it was  @accounts with an s
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

First let's anlayze this error message :

```
error: undefined local variable or method `account' for #
```

It's saying that a variable `account` is undefined, so let's look at your method :

```
def find_login
    @accounts  = Account.find_by_email(params[:search].to_s.downcase)

    unless @accounts.nil?
        flash[:success] = "Email found! An email has been sent."
        UserMailer.login_recovery(account).deliver
      else
        flash[:error] = "Email NOT found!"  if params[:search] && !params[:search].empty?
    end
end
```

In ruby, `@` denote instance variables and a normal variable does not have any special symbol.

So your checking if an account exist with `@accounts  = Account.find_by_email(params[:search].to_s.downcase)`. Note that you're using `@accounts` to store the result of your query!

Next thing you do, you check if `@accounts` is `nil`. Everything is good so far. Your account, if found, will be store in that variable.

Now, you call `login_recovery` with `account` as parameter. `account` is different from `@accounts` since it's a normal variable and does not have the same name. That's where the error is thrown.

As @[spickermann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38253952) said in his answer, use `@accounts`.

I wanted to add a step-by-step explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the step-by-step explanation @Marc-Andre . That helps to understand the process.